# MySQL Connector/NET for ASP.NET 4.0 that works with MySQL 4.0.xx?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, connector

I'm trying to connect my asp.net 4.0 application to a MySQL 4.0.xx database.

I have MySQL Connector/NET 6.3.5 installed. It works great with MySQL 5+, but it says it does not support anything prior to version 5.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade to MySQL 5.0 and then 5.1. Before you upgrade you should backup your database and test it on the new MySQL version on a VM or another Machine before committing to the new version completely.

Comment: As much as I'd like to upgrade the database server, I don't own it sadly. I just connect to it with SELECT privileges only. I made a compromise and installed MySQL Connector/NET 5 instead. It works with MySQL 4, but doesnt support nice stuff in Visual Studio such as being available for use in SQLDataSource control.